# Run scarpy project from djnago views,py

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a scraper which will extract email ids from website urls , and i want this to integrate this to my Django views.py module.
I have my project structure as follows :

> > > > emails
> > > > emails
> > > > -**init.py**
> > > > -asgi.py
> > > > -settings.py
> > > > -urls.py
>
> > > e_scrapy  (django-app)
> > > email_scrapper  //scrapy project
> > > spiders
> > > --init__.py
> > > -email_extraction.py
> > > **init**.py
> > > items.py
> > > middlewares.py
> > > pipelines.py
> > > settings.py
> > > scrapy.cfg

```
 __init__.py
 admin.py
 apps.py
 models.py
 tests.py
 urls.py //manually added
 views.py
```

my email_extraction.py have this code::

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Request
import re
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import openpyxl
from time import sleep
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path
from tldextract import extract

class EmailExtractor(CrawlSpider):

    name='emailex111'
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.queries=[]
        self.emaillist=[]
        self.row=0
        self.write_wb=xlsxwriter.Workbook('emails_list.xlsx')
        self.sheet=self.write_wb.add_worksheet('sheet1')
        self.filename=filename
        
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(self.filename)

        self.save_file=self.filename+"_emails.txt"
        sh=wb.active
        for i in range(1,sh.max_row+1):
            cell_obj=sh.cell(row=i,column=1)
            tsd, td, tsu = extract(cell_obj.value)
            search_query=td + '.' + tsu
            #pass_val='"@'+str(search_query)+'" Email Address'
            self.queries.append(search_query)


    def start_requests(self):
        WINDOW_SIZE="1920,1080"
        
        path="C:/Users/iamfa/OneDrive/Desktop/SCRAPY/email_extraction/email_extraction/spiders/msedgedriver.exe"
        options=webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        #options.add_argument("--headless")
        #options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        browser=webdriver.Edge(options=options,executable_path=path)
        url_list=[]
        for query in self.queries:  # iterate through queries
            url="https://www.bing.com/search?q=%40"+str(query)+"+%22Email+Address%22"
            try:
                browser.get(url)
                links=browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'cite')    
                for link in links:
                    url_list.append(link.text)
            except:
                continue
                

            resultno=0
            for results in url_list:
                
                if resultno==5:
                    break
                try:
                    resultno+=1
                    yield SeleniumRequest(
                        url=results,
                        callback=self.parse,
                        wait_until=EC.presence_of_element_located(
                            (By.TAG_NAME, "html")),
                        dont_filter=True
                    )
                except:
                    continue
            url_list.clear()
            self.write_wb.close()
   
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        file1=open(self.save_file,'a')
        
        EMAIL_REGEX =r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+"
        emails = re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, str(response.text))
        for email in emails:
            self.emaillist.append(email.group())
            
        for email in set(self.emaillist):
            if "png" or ".svg" or ".webp" or ".jpg" or ".jpeg" or ".wixpress" not in email:
                if "j" and "doe" not in email:
                    file1.write(email+"\n")
                    self.sheet.write(self.row,1,email)
                    self.row+=1
                #yield{
                    #"emails": email
                #}
            
        self.emaillist.clear()
```

also my views.py :

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from email_scrapper import EmailExtractor

process=EmailExtractor(CrawlerProcess)
process.start
process.stop
```

i don't know I am new to using scrapy and trying ton integrate it so i can make a user friendly interface, is there a way i can integrate above email_extraxtion.py spider in my views.py and run it such a way that whenever i input from front end a call from views.py to scrapy spider is made and the data starts extracting and returns me a text file?

If you need my other files to check you can ask them too but i feel this much details are sufficent for solving this problem

Comment: It would make much more sense to run your spider as a script rather than try to integrate the entire scrapy project structure into your django project.

Comment: But I want it to Be User Interface as the people who are gonna work on this are not gonna be developers

Comment: So?  What does this user interface allow the users to do?

Comment: find emails based on domains

Comment: your question is too broad... I suggest familiarizing yourself with the scrapy framework

Comment: I am learning :)

Comment: What is it you think you are gaining by keeping the whole scrapy project structure intact?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with scrapy, but judging from the code you posted, you do not have any django views to handle user HTTP requests. In `views.py` you are missing something like:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class ScrapyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        process=EmailExtractor(CrawlerProcess)
        process.start()  # here the method needs to be called
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

Then, in `urls.py` you should add:

```py
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import ScrapyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('scrape/', ScrapyView.as_view(), name='scrapy-view'),
]
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base